# Office 365 Outlook API (Exchange Admin Center)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, office365api

I've been looking around for some documentation on how (if) I can interact with the Exchange Admin Center in our Office 365 tenant.

Specifically, I'm just looking to get a list of users from Exchange Admin Center > Protection > Action Center  (users currently blocked from sending due to spam) via C#

Also remove an email address from that same list as well.

I've seen various sites, including microsoft's, that mention a REST API for a variety of purposes with Office 365 - but nothing that I'm quite looking for.

I can see Fiddler, for example, using outlook.office365.com/ecp/DDI.... as I'm manually interacting with the Exchange Admin Center > Protection > Action Center

Am I just missing where this information is?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of API's available for Exchange, but the public of them are for interfacing as a client. For managing the Exchange Server itself, your best bet would be the [Exchange Management Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326155.aspx). This is a PowerShell tool set for Exchange. You can call into these from C#, see [Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) for details.

Comment: Hey, Marc. I came to the same approach but the Powershell requires you to login and it has an interactive login.